# Remove custom script from Google Spreadsheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a google spreadsheet with a custom script to update stuff.  This sheet has been copied a few times and it currently has 2 scripts projects in the script editor. One of these is now old and should be deleted to avoid confusion.

Searching how to do this mentions a Script Manager menu option that is no longer available.  Does anyone know how I can now delete a scripts project from a google sheet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hah - of course as soon as I ask I find it.  Open the script project to delete and "delete" is under the file menu.

Comment: Could you maybe expand this answer? I have the same issue but I can't find how to delete the script...

Comment: Maybe it was under File menu, but it is not anymore, at least I don't see it there...

Comment: You have to go into the Tools->Scripts from the sheet - and then in the script editor it's under File.  It's now Delete Project but i suspect it does the same. It was over 2 years since I wrote the original!

Answer (score 7):

Currently, you must go to script.google.com , go to "My Projects" and find the project (google sheet) to which the script is connected, press the 3dots at the dots at the end of the line, and select "Delete forever". Done.

[image]

Comment: If you are not the owner of the spreadsheet that the script is associated with, Delete forever will not be available.  Another option is to delete all of the functions in the script, so nothing runs when it is called.