# google spreadsheet script editor: delete a project

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-apps-script-editor

I have two script projects for a spreadsheet. One was a temp one for development testing. I want to delete the temp one. When I click on script editor it shows both projects, and I can select one, but there is no option for deleting.

Also when I open the project itself there is no delete option. 
I have seen other SO threads (such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28084646/remove-custom-script-from-google-spreadsheet)), but it seems the interface is changed since then.

Attached the screenshots. [image]

Script Editor File menu:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure that you are the owner of the script.

I've tried to replicate your issue in other scripts which I don't own and it seems that I cannot see a `Delete Project...` option under `File` menu.

But with my owned script, there is a `Delete Project...` option. See screenshot.
[image]

Here's a reference post: [How can I remove a project from a Google Spreadsheet?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37801173/how-can-i-remove-a-project-from-a-google-spreadsheet)

**UPDATE (based from OP's comment):**

*You must be the owner of the spreadsheet to show the `Delete Project...` option.*

Comment: Although I had created the projects and scripts, I wasn't the owner of the spreadsheet and it was only shared to me. Thanks for your answer. Seems the ownership of the spreadsheet is important to show the delete project option.