# How can I delete a project execution into Google script

Tags: google-apps-script

I don't find any option or button for deleting one or more execution of a Google Script. It is possible ?

I want to purge all my developpemet exécution.

Comment: A solution now is in [thread 54941355](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54941355/disable-or-reset-the-execution-transcript-in-google-apps-script).

Answer (score 0):

You may refer with this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44379143/google-spreadsheet-script-editor-delete-a-project). Make sure that you are the owner of the spreadsheet to show the `Delete Project...` option under `File` menu..

Comment: No, I'm on GSuite Developper Hub, when I list all the execution of a script. I want to delete all of them but not the project