# Disable or reset the Execution Transcript in Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-apps-script-editor

Is it possible to disable or reset the Execution Transcript in Google Apps Script?

If not, what would be the best way to run a script that requires sensitive access tokens for API calls?

Comment: Execution transcripts are automatically cleared after a set time or after next run

Comment: @TheMaster, thanks for the input and sorry my question wasn't so clear. What I meant to ask was if it's possible to manually reset the execution transcript once the script has ran, without having to wait for the next run or a pre-defined amount of time.

Comment: AFAIK, No......

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a time-based trigger to invoke a simple dummy script:

```
function clearIt() {
  Logger.log("hi");
}
```

This script could be invoked every minute, or specifically invoked via one-time trigger to occur after specific other functions. If you go the one-time route you'll need to delete the invoking trigger to avoid accumulation:

```
function sensitive() {
  ...
  ScriptApp.newTrigger("newExecutionTranscript")
    .timeBased().after(1) // runs at up to 15m later
    .create();
}

function newExecutionTranscript(e) {
  const invoker = (!e) ? null : ScriptApp.getProjectTriggers()
      .filter(function (t) {
        return t.getUniqueId() === e.triggerUid;
      })[0];
  if (invoker)
    ScriptApp.deleteTrigger(invoker);
  Logger.log("Done");
}
```

References

- [Time-driven trigger event object](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#time-driven_events)
- [`Trigger#getUniqueId`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/script/trigger#getuniqueid)
- [`ClockTriggerBuilder#after`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/script/clock-trigger-builder#after(Integer))

Comment: Thank you tehhowch, I will go with your solution as I think there really isn't a more clean way to clear the execution log. Thanks again!